# Will my Minecraft Server progress be wiped if I use a new hard drive?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I currently have an older Mac computer with a small hard drive. I recently purchased a new drive, and I am moving everything over by way of a dual-bay drive docking station.

However, I'm concerned about my progress on servers. Would they be wiped by this, or will they be safe?

Comment: Well, servers are located in places other than your own computer, and data is also stored in other places than your own computer. So, essentially, no.

Comment: No, your character is saved on the server. Nothing should be saved locally on your hard drive

Answer (score 2):

Your hard drive should store no information about your server profiles, except for some metadata, like the server's IP and your user information (if it has been saved).

As long as you log in to the same account after you switch hard drives, your servers list may be empty but the servers themselves will still have record of your existence.

However, your singleplayer worlds and other things will be wiped in the process, so make sure you have them backed up.

---

If you want to be *completely* safe and be 100% certain everything makes it over (including your IP list, singleplayer worlds, and settings), you can just copy your Minecraft home folder. Instructions:

1. Open a Finder window
2. Press the key combination <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>
3. Paste this exact text into the box: `~/Library/Application Support`
4. Look for a folder named `minecraft`, and copy it to a thumb drive.

Note: If you don't have enough space in the thumb drive, you may ignore the `assets` folder.

To restore your Minecraft data, run the Launcher once on the new hard drive, and then follow steps 1 to 3 above. This time, copy the `minecraft` folder BACK to the `Application Support` window you have open.

Alternatively, if you're just directly cloning the drives or doing a copy/paste of your user data directly, your Minecraft save folder will still make it. It's still better to  be sure, though.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments by Kaizerwolf and ChaseC, all of your player data and changes made on a server are stored on that server. This is true for both mac and pc client versions of minecraft. In fact, you could download minecraft on a new computer, and as long as you use the same player account, all of your server progress will be retained (as long as the server is up and running). Doing this may or may not cause problems for single player maps, but your multiplayer progress will be unaffected.

Answer (score 0):

Your data on the servers won't be deleted as long as you use the same account.